# CustomerControl ZoomableScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I try to create a customer control that is capable of zoom and some other features.

I think scroll viewer is the right base class. So i created a UserControl in the first atempt that derives from scrollviewer. But a UserControl can not contain named Content. Basically my control should behave like a any customer control.

So i read that i should implement the zoom behavior in a lookless customer control instead of a usercontrol.

Now I am curios how to get the control template from my first user control atempt into my customer control template:

```
<ScrollViewer.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ZoomViewer}">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" ManipulationStarting="ContentControl_ManipulationStarting" ManipulationDelta="ContentControl_ManipulationDelta"
                            IsManipulationEnabled="true">
                <ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="PART_ScaleTransform"/>
                </ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Loaded="ScrollContentPresenter_Loaded"/>
            </ContentControl>
            <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
            <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
            <Slider Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="0"
                    x:Name="PART_Slider" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ScrollViewer.Template>
```

How do i add simple zoom behavior to a scroll viewer without xaml.
Maybe my atempt is totally wrong but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult understanding your question but I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <Grid Width="200" Height="200" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=scaleControl, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=scaleControl, Path=Value}" />
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Button Width="64" Height="48">Hello</Button>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Separator Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" />
    <ScrollBar Name="scaleControl" Grid.Row="2" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" Orientation="Horizontal" />
</Grid>
```